# Adjust div height to div parent's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a nav panel and I need to adjust the different option's styles to the parent div. For example, I need to adjust the background color of the options to the parent div (Paint the color in the full height of the parent div).
[image]

This is the code:

```
<div class="text-center text-muted"> <div class="container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #e9ecef;">
   <div class="row mt8" id="nav_panel">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="nav_panel_monday" style="background-color: rgb(0, 160, 157);">
    <a id="nav_href_monday" href="#" style="color: white;">Monday</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2" id="nav_panel_tuesday">
    <a id="nav_href_tuesday" href="#">Tuesday</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2" id="nav_panel_wednesday">
    <a id="nav_href_wednesday" href="#">Wednesday</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2" id="nav_panel_thursday">
    <a id="nav_href_thursday" href="#">Thursday</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2" id="nav_panel_friday">
    <a id="nav_href_friday" href="#">Friday</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="card-body">
  <div id="div_hidden_monday"></div>
  <div id="div_hidden_tuesday" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div id="div_hidden_wednesday" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div id="div_hidden_thursday" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div id="div_hidden_friday" style="display: none;"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.card-header {
    padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
#nav_panel {
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.col-md-2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to remove padding of the `.card-header` and add padding to the child elements. Like this
https://jsfiddle.net/bhusalhari99/sruLkt2b/3/

hope it will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

> For the time being using `padding` and `margin` issue is fixed but You
>   need to re-right the `nav` HTML structure using `nav` and `ul` `li`
>   like [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/#nav)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card-header {
  padding: 0 15px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

.card-header a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#nav_panel {
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.col-md-2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center text-muted">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #e9ecef;">
        <div class="row mt8" id="nav_panel">
          <div class="col-md-2" id="nav_panel_monday" style="background-color: rgb(0, 160, 157);">
            <a id="nav_href_monday" href="#" style="color: white;">Monday</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2" id="nav_panel_tuesday">
            <a id="nav_href_tuesday" href="#">Tuesday</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2" id="nav_panel_wednesday">
            <a id="nav_href_wednesday" href="#">Wednesday</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2" id="nav_panel_thursday">
            <a id="nav_href_thursday" href="#">Thursday</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2" id="nav_panel_friday">
            <a id="nav_href_friday" href="#">Friday</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div id="div_hidden_monday"></div>
        <div id="div_hidden_tuesday" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div id="div_hidden_wednesday" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div id="div_hidden_thursday" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div id="div_hidden_friday" style="display: none;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```